# Is possible run message broker as a windows service in wso2?

Tags: wso2, windows-services, wso2-message-broker, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I already was able to create API Manager and Enterprise Integrator as service, following this tutorials: https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Installing+as+a+Windows+Service
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Installing+as+a+Windows+Service

But i can't found a tutorial to show me the way to configure Message Broker to be installed as windows service. Could anyone help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the solution from that. Unfortunately the WSO2 don't have the support to create a message broker as a service yet. Been like that, you can't do that yet, unless you find anothers way out of the original platform to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to do that through the YAJSW by installing the version of 11.03.

I tried and resolved the same by keeping the ESB and Message Broker as a different services in the windows service.

Just change the name and convention as per the services and maintain the uniqueness which you want to execute as a service.

Also, do the steps as provide by the YAJSW steps to install as a service for both either EI or ESB and Message Broker.

Follow the below link for the steps,

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Installing+as+a+Windows+Service#InstallingasaWindowsService-SettinguptheYAJSWwrapperconfigurationfile

Thanks,
Praveen Tallakokula